# Can I detect whether a child process has finished io processing on exit?

Tags: node.js

In my program I am spawning a child process which is doing some I/O work. I have subscribe to the exit event for the child process. However, the file which is being written still seems to be being used after the exit event has fired.

From the nodejs docs https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_class_childprocess

> Note that when the 'exit' event is triggered, child process stdio
>   streams might still be open.

How can I detect that the file processing has completed? I have tried using lsof but it takes a lot of time (around 10 seconds to run once, and I end up executing it multiple times as in the first instant, the file may not be free)

Comment: Can `close` event do the trick? You can create something like a context that will manage your child processes and know the state of each process. Have variables like `exited`, `closed`, `workin`, `waitingForClose` or somethink like that.

Comment: Wow! I don't know why I was under the impression that close event is fired before exit. After your comment, I read the documentation of the close event and its clear that is exactly what I was looking for. I am sure I saw that before but did not process it that way because of the bias in my head that close would be emitted before exit. The biases we carry in our heads! Thanks for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can you use `close` event to check when all stdio streams have closed.

Per [Node.js v9.2.1 Documentation - ChildProcess](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_class_childprocess)

> **Event: 'close'**
>
> - **code**  The exit code if the child exited on its own.
> - **signal**  The signal by which the child process was terminated.
>
> The 'close' event is emitted when the stdio streams of a child process
>   have been closed. This is distinct from the 'exit' event, since
>   multiple processes might share the same stdio streams.